# Any way to get url params in Next.js custom document?

Tags: next.js, internationalization, i18next, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm working on a multi-language statically built (next export) Next.js site. I can't use next internationalization so I've had to hack together a solution, mostly based on this [nextjs-18n-static-page-starter](https://github.com/Xairoo/nextjs-i18n-static-page-starter)

My page structure looks like this:

```
pages
 ┣ [lang]
 ┃ ┣ category
 ┃ ┃ ┣ [slug].js
 ┃ ┃ ┗ index.js
 ┃ ┗ index.js
 ┣ _app.js
 ┣ _document.js
 ┗ index.js
```

I would like to set the html lang attribute in a custom document. Is there any way to dynamically pull this from the url at the document level?

I have this hacky solution going, but it doesn't update when the user changes their language in the app (which does correctly redirect to a new url):

```
export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    const queryLang = this?.props?.__NEXT_DATA__?.query?.lang;
    const lang = ( queryLang === null || queryLang === undefined ) ? DEFAULT_LANG : queryLang;

    return (
      <Html lang={lang}>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: `_document` only runs on the server, any change done on the client-side will not be picked up. You might have to do some DOM manipulation in `_app` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Setting it in the app did the trick. Here's the code I ended up with (thanks to @juliomalves for pointing me in the right direction)...

```
const App = function ({ Component, pageProps }) {
    i18next.changeLanguage(pageProps.language);

    useEffect(() => {
        const lang = ( pageProps.language === null || 
          pageProps.language === undefined ) 
          ? DEFAULT_LANG 
          : pageProps.language;
        document.documentElement.lang = lang;
     }, [pageProps.language]);
    return <Component {...pageProps} />;
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Next.js v10, if you're using the built-in [i18n routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing), Next will automatically set the `lang` attribute of the document.

if your language is `en-US` all you need to do is add the following in you `next.config.js` file

```js
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en-US"],
    defaultLocale: "en-US",
  },
  ...
}
```

From the documentation:

> ### Search Engine Optimization
>
> Since Next.js knows what language the user is visiting it will
> automatically add the `lang` attribute to the `<html>` tag.
>
> Next.js doesn't know about variants of a page so it's up to you to add
> the `hreflang` meta tags using `next/head`. You can learn more about
> `hreflang` in the [Google Webmasters documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions?visit_id=637543390382043375-2619640130&rd=1).